# Iterate over a text file line by line within a for loop in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I have a txt file that looks like this called `locations.txt`:

```
location-1a
location-2c
location-3d
location-4
location-5a
...
```

I wish to iterate over the `locations.txt` file within my for loop, each location should be used for 5 nodes, then the next location should be used. so for example, I want the following commands to run,

```
server create --location location-1a node-1
server create --location location-1a node-2
server create --location location-1a node-3
server create --location location-1a node-4
server create --location location-1a node-5
server create --location location-2c node-6

.....
```

So far, I only have the following script called `script.sh` with takes an argument from the cli. I can't change the location like I want to.

```
mapfile -t locationArr < ~/Documents/files/locations.txt
serverCounter=1
locationCounter=1
counter=1

counter=1
for (( i = 1; i <= $1; i++ ))
do
 server create --location $locationArr[$locationCounter] node-$i
 counter=$((counter+1))
 if [ $counter == 5 ]
 then
  counter=1
  locationCounter=$((locationCounter+1))
done
```

I want something like

```
if counter == 5:
 counter=0
 nextline
```

So for example if I run `script.sh 11`, I want the following result,

```
server create --location location-1a node-1
server create --location location-1a node-2
server create --location location-1a node-3
server create --location location-1a node-4
server create --location location-1a node-5
server create --location location-2c node-6
server create --location location-2c node-7
server create --location location-2c node-8
server create --location location-2c node-9
server create --location location-2c node-10
server create --location location-3d node-11
```

How do I iterate over the location.txt file within my for loop? Should I convert the text file into some sort of list variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash)

Comment: Your `for` loop isn't reading the file at all. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: I know it isn't, I want it to read it on top of my for loop, I want the for loop to be the main loop while having a separate counter for the file

Comment: What exactly is the command-line argument for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my attempt:

```
counter=1
while IFS= read -r line
do
    for (( i=1; i <= 5 && $counter <= $1; i++ ))
    do
     server create --location $line node-$counter
     counter=$((counter+1))
    done 
done < ~/Documents/files/locations.txt
```

The output with 11:

```
server create --location location-1a node-1
server create --location location-1a node-2
server create --location location-1a node-3
server create --location location-1a node-4
server create --location location-1a node-5
server create --location location-2c node-6
server create --location location-2c node-7
server create --location location-2c node-8
server create --location location-2c node-9
server create --location location-2c node-10
server create --location location-3d node-11
```

Comment: I guess that should be `node-"$counter"` but the question is vaguely confusing on this point.

Comment: Yeah, I realized this now. My output doesn't match to the OP question.

Comment: I think I got now what he wants.

Comment: hey how does the `i <= 5 && $counter <= $1` part work? how does it go to the next line within the while loop?

Comment: For every line in the file. It'll loop on all valid i, from 1 to 5. In order to do this iteration, it'll have also to satisfy the condition that `counter` is still less than the supplied command line value.
I see one issue now, it'll keep reading the input file even when the `count` is beyond `$1` but won't spit any output. If this is an issue, you can use `break` after the inner for loop once this condition is met to stop reading the input file. Let me know if this isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

General outline:

- outer loop for reading locations from `locations.txt`
- inner loop for generating a max of 5 nodes for a given location
- each time a node is generated increment a count
- if the counter > input 'max' then break out of loops

One implementation of the above:

```
max=${1}
curr=1

while read -r location
do
    for i in {1..5}
    do
        echo "server create --location ${location} node-${curr}"
        curr=$((curr+1))
        [ ${curr} -gt ${max} ] && break 2
    done
done < locations.txt
```

Test run with `max=${1}=11`:

```
server create --location location-1a node-1
server create --location location-1a node-2
server create --location location-1a node-3
server create --location location-1a node-4
server create --location location-1a node-5
server create --location location-2c node-6
server create --location location-2c node-7
server create --location location-2c node-8
server create --location location-2c node-9
server create --location location-2c node-10
server create --location location-3d node-11
```

OP can add additional checks for `max` being an integer greater than 0.

Comment: Nice! I like `break 2` .. i completely forgot about this construct.

Answer (score 1):

Done with single loop, no Bashism POSIX syntax:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

i=0
while [ $i -lt "$1" ] && {
  [ $((i % 5)) -ne 0 ] || IFS= read -r line || [ "$line" ]
}; do
  server create --location "$line" "node-$((i = i + 1))"
done <locations.txt
```

Comment: Nice, but you may need to limit the output to the command line value `$1` not the end of locations.txt

Comment: Your solution continues generating output for all lines in locations.txt. From the OP sample output, the output needs to stop when it reaches the given limit, `$1`.

Comment: Great ... i have a Q, what does `|| [ "$line" ]` do exactly? It seems to work fine without it as well. Is it to avoid empty lines in locations.txt ?

Comment: @hesham_EE It returns `true` if the last line does not end with a `newline` character. Otherwise the last `read` would cause the condition to fail and the last line would not be processed.